# Which lifecycle method to use when component is dependent on two props in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently, in our project we are using `componentWillReceiveProps` method to process props.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
   if(nextprops.userData != this.props.userData) {
      //...do something
   }
}
```

Now, the issue here is that some other prop, `employeeData` is required in conjunction with `userData` to do something. Is there some way I can do it in here or maybe some other lifecycle method that will aid in doing this?

Edit: I am using class components and cannot use functional components here.

Comment: So whats the problem to add it to the condition?..

Comment: @DennisVash I cannot do that because the component will receive the props at different times...

Comment: So what? Check if the props received...